# Scaling android app to different screen sizes

Tags: android

So I'm working on scaling my application to different screen sizes. Right now Its optimized for a 10.1 inch screen but I'm working to get it to run on the kindle fire which has a 7 inch screen. I'm only using relative layouts. As of now my background scales perfectly but the image buttons ontop of the background don't scale and I was wondering if there was a reason for this. Also I use margins to adjust the positions of my buttons, is this okay for scaling sizes?

Comment: Are your button drawables located in the xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi directories? If I am not mistaken the Galaxy 10.1 is xhdpi and the fire is mdpi

Comment: They are all in mdpi which works for my transformer which is 10.1

Comment: I think that your drawable is supposed to be in the hdpi for the transformer. IIRC that tablet has an actual density of like 192 or 194 so I think it gets bumped up to hdpi(240).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always define  in your manifest because the [default values can](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) change from one version to another.

But if you want to support xlarge screens then you're stuck because this attribute was introduced in API level 9 (android 2.3). You have to create two different APKs, one for android versions >= 2.3 and the other for the older ones.

Since it's a common issue, android provides a nice way to [publish only one application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) on the market even if you use multiple APKs.

Answer (score 5):

to support application on different screen refer the following  link

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

and to scale image button use **nine patch images** they scale well.

**Also I use margins to adjust the positions of my buttons, is this okay for scaling sizes?**

yes it okay.